# What is correct location of src.zip file in JDK?

Tags: java

What should be the correct location of **src.zip** in JDK?

Should it be `JAVA_HOME/lib/src.zip`?

or

Should it be `JAVA_HOME/src.zip`?

Which one is correct?

JDK version - openjdk11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the version of Java you are using, with

- Java 9+ it should be `$JAVA_HOME/lib/src.zip`<sup>**1**</sup>
- Java 8 and earlier it should be `$JAVA_HOME/src.zip`

<sup>**1**</sup><sub>See also [Project Jigsaw](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/). More specifically, [JEP 201](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/201) and [JEP 220](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220).</sub>

Comment: Won't it cause error for the program which tries to access the src.zip file?

Comment: Java 9 was released in September 2017. They're up to java 14 now. Clearly the world has not ended.

Answer (score 0):

mostly, the JDK source code is named src. zip , and located at the root folder of the JDK installed path.
in your question Java 11, it is  `$JAVA_HOME/lib/src.zip` and it will be different in other versions. *stating the Java version that you are currently using in the question will help you to find a better answer*

Comment: I thought there will be a standard location of storing the src.zip file across all the versions so I didn't mention the version of JDK I am dealing with.

Comment: It depends according to the version you are using. You can mention it on your question by editing it.

Comment: I posted this question cause I was getting JAVA_HOME/src.zip on openjdk8 and JAVA_HOME/lib/src.zip on openjdk11.