# Intellij: Javadoc I can't see description of the methods, class in java documentation after ctrl+b

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

I can't see description of the methods, class in java documentation after clicking ctrl+b in Intellij. How can I turn it on or should i update my doc?

Screenshots:

[Without description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zo0WG.png)

[I would like to have something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjTAF.jpg)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the `File | Project Structure | SDKs`, go to the `Sourcepath`, and attach this JDK's source code file (often named src.zip).
See the detailed steps/images here: https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-attach-jdk-source-code-to-intellij-idea/

The source code file (src.zip) often comes from `$JAVA_HOME/lib/src.zip` and `$JAVA_HOME/src.zip` from your downloaded JDK[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61114315/2331527).

Another easier way is to go to `File | Project Structure | SDKs`, click the `+` icon to download one JDK which would configure the sourcepath by default.

The Documentation paths mentioned by @Müseyib Ələkbər is for Quick Documentation popup. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#configure-external-documentation

Answer (score 0):

Go "File->Project Structure" and add the source for the documentation

[image]